# Как работать с массивом в создании игры 3 в ряд

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Когда нажимаю на Кружочек (это как конфетка в Candy Crash), то он становится `SetActive(true)`. Я хочу, чтобы все 4 стороны (верх, низ, правый, левый) тоже стали SetActive = true. Чтобы последующем, можно было их только двигать. Но, когда я нажимаю, то например, правый кружочек не становится `SetActive`, но зато True становится правый кружочек от самого первого созданного кружочка.

```
.....
.....
.....
.*... <----  Вот этот
```

Вот код класса для кружочка:

```
public class CircleControl : MonoBehaviour {

public int column;
public int row;
private Doska doska;
private GameObject otherCircle;
private Animator scaler;
private Vector2 tempPos;
public bool SetActive = false;
public int nesw; //north = 1 east = 2 south = 3 west = 4
public int TargetX;
public int TargetY;


void Start () {
    scaler = GetComponent<Animator>();
    scaler.SetInteger("ScalePlus", 1);
    doska = FindObjectOfType<Doska>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
private void OnMouseDown()
{

    SetActive = true;
    scaler.SetInteger("ScalePlus", 2);//Анимация

    otherCircle = doska.allCircles[column + 1, row];
    otherCircle.GetComponent<CircleControl>().SetActive = true;
    //doska.allCircles[column + 1, row].GetComponent<CircleControl>().SetActive = true;
    //doska.allCircles[column + 1, row].GetComponent<CircleControl>().nesw = 2;

    doska.allCircles[column, row + 1].GetComponent<CircleControl>().SetActive = true;
    doska.allCircles[column, row + 1].GetComponent<CircleControl>().nesw = 1;

    //doska.allCircles[column - 1, row].GetComponent<CircleControl>().SetActive = true;
    //doska.allCircles[column - 1, row].GetComponent<CircleControl>().nesw = 4;

    //doska.allCircles[column, row - 1].GetComponent<CircleControl>().SetActive = true;
    //doska.allCircles[column, row - 1].GetComponent<CircleControl>().nesw = 3;
}

void MoveCircles()
{
    if(SetActive == true && nesw == 2 && column < doska.width) // направо
    {
        otherCircle = doska.allCircles[column + 1, row];
        otherCircle.GetComponent<CircleControl>().column -= 1;
        column += 1;
    }
    else if (SetActive == true && nesw == 1 && row < doska.height)// вверх
    {
        if (SetActive)
        {
            otherCircle = doska.allCircles[column , row + 1];
            otherCircle.GetComponent<CircleControl>().column -= 1;
            row += 1;
        }
    }
    else if (SetActive == true && nesw == 4 && column > 0)//влево
    {
        if (SetActive)
        {
            otherCircle = doska.allCircles[column - 1, row];
            otherCircle.GetComponent<CircleControl>().column += 1;
            column -= 1;
        }
    }
    else if (SetActive == true && nesw == 2 && row > 0)// вниз
    {
        if (SetActive)
        {
            otherCircle = doska.allCircles[column, row - 1];
            otherCircle.GetComponent<CircleControl>().row += 1;
            row -= 1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Код взаимодействия кружочка с его соседями в методе `OnMouseDown()`

А вот код класса для доски:

```
public class Doska : MonoBehaviour {

public int width;
public int height;
public GameObject tilePref;
public GameObject[] circles;
private Tile [,] tiles;
public GameObject[,] allCircles;

void Start () {
    tiles = new Tile[width, height];
    allCircles = new GameObject[width, height];
    Nastroyka();
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Nastroyka () {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            Vector2 cleanPos = new Vector2 (i, j);
            GameObject bgTile = Instantiate(tilePref, cleanPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            bgTile.transform.parent = this.transform;
            bgTile.name = "( " + i + ", " + j + " )";
            int circlesUse = Random.Range(0, circles.Length);
            GameObject circle = Instantiate(circles[circlesUse], cleanPos, Quaternion.identity);
            circle.transform.parent = this.transform;
            circle.name = "( " + i + ", " + j + " )";
            allCircles[i, j] = circle;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Хз, как форматировать, извиняюсь, не ругайтесь
Надо смотреть на OnMouseDown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если все создание вашего поля происходит в методе `Nastroyka()` и нигде больше вы ничего не делаете - то проблема в том, что вы создаете все `CircleControl` правильно и в нужных местах, но не задаете ни одному из них значения `row` и `column`, что означает, что у всех ваших "кружочков" значения `row` и `column` равны 0.

Если это так, то метод нужно поправить следующим образом:

```
private void Nastroyka () {
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        Vector2 cleanPos = new Vector2 (i, j);
        GameObject bgTile = Instantiate(tilePref, cleanPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        bgTile.transform.parent = this.transform;
        bgTile.name = "( " + i + ", " + j + " )";
        int circlesUse = Random.Range(0, circles.Length);
        GameObject circle = Instantiate(circles[circlesUse], cleanPos, Quaternion.identity);
        circle.transform.parent = this.transform;
        circle.name = "( " + i + ", " + j + " )";
        //получаем у объекта circle компонент CircleControl и
        //устанавливаем в переменные row и column нужные значения
        var circleControl = circle.GetComponent<CircleControl>();
        circleControl.row = j;
        circleControl.column = i;
        allCircles[i, j] = circle;
    }
}
```

Таким образом, если у всех кружочков значения `row` и `column` равны 0, то какой бы вы кружочек не тыкнули, то `SetActive(true)` всегда будет становиться правый кружочек от самого первого созданного кружочка.

А если вы еще где-то заполняете эти переменные, то вы не скинули весь необходимый код, чтобы понять вашу проблему.